# AttributeError: Can't get attribute '_unpickle_block' (My dump and load versions of pandas are same)

Tags: python, pandas, pickle

```
AttributeError: Can't get attribute '_unpickle_block' on <module 'pandas._libs.internals'
```

I know this question has been answered before. The solution told was to make the dumb and load version of pandas same. I'm using 1.3.5 version in jupyter for loading and the same version in vs code. But still the same error.

this is the dump code in jupyter:

```
import pickle
pickle.dump(popular_df,open('popular.pkl','wb'))
```

vs code to load:

```
popular_df = pickle.load(open('popular.pkl','rb'))
```